# ggplot for various values of a column in a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if the question title was not very clear.

I have data that has the following columns:

1. `Total number of ads` #Values range from 4 to 25
2. `Position of ad` #value ranges from 1 to 25 (max of `total number of ads`)
3. `Impressions for each ad` #values of type double

Now, I want to create plots of position vs average impressions for each value of `total number of ads`. That is, when `total number of ads` is 10, get a plot of `position of ad` on x-axis and average of all `Impressions` at each position.

I did a generic plot without classifying for each value of `Total number of ads` using:

```
ggplot(colors, aes(x=factor(colors$`Position of Ad in Break`), y=colors$Impressions)) + 
 stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar") + 
 ggtitle("average impressions per ad position by total ads") +
 labs(x="Ad Position", y="Average Impressions")
```

I tried doing a for loop with all values:

```
for(i in colors$`Total number of Ads in Break`){
  ggplot(colors, aes(x=factor(colors$`Position of Ad in Break` + colors$`Total number of Ads in Break`), y=colors$Impressions)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar") + 
    ggtitle("average impressions per ad position by total ads") +
    labs(x="Ad Position", y="Average Impressions")
}
```

This gave a graph that I don't understand but definitely not what i want.

Can someone help me please?

**EDIT**

I tried the loop with:

```
for(i in colors$`Total number of Ads in Break`){
  ggplot(colors, aes(x=factor(colors$`Position of Ad in Break` + i), y=colors$Impressions)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar") + 
    ggtitle("average impressions per ad position by total ads") +
    labs(x="Ad Position", y="Average Impressions")
}
```

Still does not give me what I want.

Also, sample data:

```
Impressions    Position_of_ad    Total_ads
30.95          11                19
101.41         18                23
21.99          10                19
22.23          18                21
79.42          8                 20
22.39          6                 22
15.8           10                21
46.78          14                20
57.05          12                23
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't seem to actually do anything with the loop variable `i`, so what were you hoping it would do? Are you just trying to do faceting? Any chance of some sample data?

Comment: Also, don't use `$` in `aes`.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for your time, Please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a bar plot of position vs impressions faceted by the total number of ads:

```
ggplot(colors, aes(Position_of_ad, Impressions)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
   facet_wrap(~Total_ads, ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I wanted to plot the AVERAGE of impressions for each position in each of the graphs generated. Can you please give me pointers for that?

Comment: Are you saying that for each position / ad total there are multiple records?